# PhpSpreadsheet: Tables get lost in the process

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have an Excel file that I read and write to with PhpSpreadsheet. All my tables and references disappear in the process. Is there a flag I need to set to true/false or are tables just something that PhpSpreadsheet can't handle? See screenshots of before and after export.

I've tried different true/false combos of these without any luck `setIncludeCharts(true);` and `setPreCalculateFormulas(true)`

Anything obvious I'm missing here?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("template.xlsx");

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

I suppress these notices/warnings with `error_reporting(0)` if it has anything to do with it. However that is in the PhpSpreadsheet code, which I'm not really supposed to mess with:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
> /vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php
> on line 3472
>
> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
> /vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php
> on line 3680
> ```

I also tried a different version of the same template that gave me this error:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception: Invalid cell
> coordinate 1))) in
> vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php:42
> Stack trace: #0
> vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php(111):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::coordinateFromString('1)))')
> #1 vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php(86):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::absoluteCoordinate('1)))')
> #2 vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Workbook.php(416):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::absoluteReference('1)))') #3
> vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/Workbook.php(267):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Workbook->writeDefinedNameForPrintArea(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\XMLWriter),
> Object(PhpOffice\PhpS in
> vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php
> on line 42
> ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: the tables are so called pivot tables right ?

Comment: Those tables aren't pivot tables. They are called "smart table" or "intelligent table" ("ListObject" in VBA), and afterwards they are converted to simple ranges. They are typically used to get a dropdown list with suggested or allowed values for "data validation". Maybe one of these terms help googling ...

Comment: @Asger correct, they’re used for dropdowns. So is there a way to keep them after going through the PhpSpreadsheet machine?

Comment: Bump, tips anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Smarttables use Pivottables in the background. The only way to get around that I found is to style the cells by hand.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of that? If my original excel file fetched dropdown lists from a second sheet, is it any way to keep that intact or recreate?

Comment: You can call the values from the other sheet easy by using `$spreadsheet->getSheetByName('NAME');`. for Formatting use something like this  `function cellColor($sheet, $cells, $bgColor, $fontColor) {

        $sheet->getStyle($cells)->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB($fontColor);
        $sheet->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $sheet->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB($bgColor);
    }`

Comment: Thanks! I actually don’t care about the styling getting lost. What I need is the dropdown menus to still work from one sheet to the next. Do you know how to recreate dropdown menus with phpspreadsheet?

Comment: That is a little difficult thing. You can use Autofilter [link](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/autofilters/) but there is a limitation to one Table by worksheet. You can more read about in this article [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934401/phpspreadsheet-multiple-tables-with-format-as-table-in-excel-worksheet/51278747#51278747)

Comment: Ah ok. So I’ll be limited to only one. I have like 7 as you see. Can autofilter set conditions too? So my best bet is to have all the dropdown references on the same sheet? I think that worked, but looks terrible.

Comment: This is not fully correct if you put all in one "Table" and cast autofilter to the range. Than you can sort all but you will have empty cells in the shorter colums.

Answer (score 0):

Was dealing with the same problem, couldn't find any workaround other than styling the cells by hand as Collie mentioned.

I moved over to TinyButStrong with the OpenTBS plugin instead: https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php

This plugin allowed me to open up a similar XLSX file as your screenshot with tables, dropdowns, and styling in PHP, use it as a template and edit columns/add values without losing anything as it's using a different approach.

Of course, this doesn't include all the features you might need from PhpSpreadsheet. But for simple column/values editing this was a good alternative for me and it's also very lightweight.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Awesome, I’ll check it out!